# How can i count the total number of instances of a specific data attribute in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

For example, for the following HTML, the answer would be 4. As there are 4 instances of `data-example`

```
<h1>Random text</h1>

<div data-example>
  <img src="eg.png">
</div>

<p>More random text</p>

<ul>
  <li data-example>eg1</li>
  <li data-example>eg2</li>
  <li data-example>eg3</li>
</ul>
```

Ideally, I was hoping for an inbuilt function like "get_total_instances", but i haven't found anything like this.

```js
$('[data-example]').get_total_instances(); // output should be 4
```

or

```
get_total_instances('[data-example]'); // output should be 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property of the jQuery object:

```
$("[data-example]").length
```

It tells you how many elements are in the set that you selected.

Live Example:

```js
console.log($("[data-example]").length);
```

```html
<h1>Random text</h1>

<div data-example>
  <img src="eg.png">
</div>

<p>More random text</p>

<ul>
  <li data-example>eg1</li>
  <li data-example>eg2</li>
  <li data-example>eg3</li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

And for those who are not using jQuery, here's the vanilla JavaScript equivalent:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-example]").length;
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[data-example]").length);
```

```html
<h1>Random text</h1>

<div data-example>
  <img src="eg.png">
</div>

<p>More random text</p>

<ul>
  <li data-example>eg1</li>
  <li data-example>eg2</li>
  <li data-example>eg3</li>
</ul>
```